# How to create Short code that will show specific post by ids

Tags: wordpress, post, shortcode

I have a custom post types. i want to create a short-code that will show some specific posts by id number. For eg. post with id 1, 23, 30 etc. here is how i tried to create short code

```
function success_short($atts) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array (

         'id' => null,

    'type' => 'aol_ad',

    'order' => 'date',

    'orderby' => 'title',

    'posts' => -1,



    'category' => '',

    ), $atts ) );


                            $args = array(

                        'post_type'=>$type,

                        'post_status'=>'publish',

                         'post__in' => array($id),

                        'posts_per_page'=>$posts,

                        'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')

                         );



$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

   <div class="post_wrap">


 <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

 ?>


  <div class="case_boxes col-md-3"> 

<div class="case_box_img">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

      </div>

      <div class="case_title">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
      </a>

      </div>

  </div>




        <?php


endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



    </div>



<?php else : ?>

    <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria. </p>

<?php endif; 

   }


add_shortcode('success-post', 'success_short');
```

Then I have tried to insert the short code like [success-post id="1, 23, 30"] but the short code not showing the post by that specific ids. How can i fix it? thanks

Comment: What does it show instead? Is there any output at all? Do you get the "Posts not found" message in your else statement?

Comment: it works for single id but not working for multiple ids

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode attribute values are strings by default.

So when you pass something like `"1, 23, 30"` then it is a string and you are trying to pass this string as a filter value to `post__in` which expects a PHP array.

Try this -

```
     ...
     posts__in => explode(",", str_replace(" ", "", trim($id, '"')))
     ...
```